# Excel rename sheets consecutively with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm using the below code to duplicate my excel sheets (it pops up a box asking the user how many times they want to duplicate the sheet)

```
Sub Create()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160704
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xNumber As Integer
    Dim xName As String
    Dim xActiveSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xActiveSheet = ActiveSheet
    xNumber = InputBox("Enter number of times to duplicate this sheet")
    For I = 1 To xNumber
        xName = ActiveSheet.Name
        xActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xName)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "dd-mm-yy" & I
    Next
    xActiveSheet.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I would like excel VBA to consecutively rename the sheets

The sheet to be duplicated will always be the start of the month "01-01-17" and i would like each sheet to be renamed accordingly, "02-01-17, 03-01-17 etc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN DateSerial Function (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx05d0c(v=vs.90).aspx): Returns a Date value representing a specified year, month, and day, with the time information set to midnight (00:00:00).

```
ActiveSheet.Name = Format(DateSerial(2017,I,1), "dd-mm-yy")
```